# Regex: how to replace numbers that are separated by comma with function calls to those same numbers

Tags: java, regex, vim, named-parameters

I'm trying to replace the numbers inside a function call with "descriptive" functions that simply just returns the argument they are given. Basically, to simulate named parameters in Java. For instance I would like to replace the arguments to a function:

```
func1(num1, num2, num3)
```

with:

```
func1(foo(num1), bar(num2), foobar(num3))
```

where `num1`, `num2`, `num3` are all integers and `foo(num1)` returns `num1`, `bar(num2)` returns `num2` and `foobar(num3)` returns `num3`.

In other words: all the parameters are **integers**. In my code, there are many calls to `func1(num1, num2, num3)`, and I would like to make the above replacement for them all.

I would like to do so using a regular expression and have so far  tried this (for the sake of simplicity, let's fix the number of arguments to 3):

```
:%s/([1-9]*), ([1-9]*), ([1-9]*)/foo(\1), bar(\2), foobar(\3)/
```

which is not the right regex (most likely syntactically wrong but I'm not sure, as I'm not very familiar with regex expressions).
I've tried variations of the above regex, but nothing yields the correct result.

If someone knows how to actually write a regular expression for this, it would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I'm using Vim as my editor.

Comment: What text editor are you doing this regex replacement in?

Comment: I'm using vim as my editor.

Comment: Can there be any number of arguments, some numbers and some not?

Comment: Good points - I have edited the question accordingly to address these things.

Comment: You need to escape the parentheses to create capture groups.

Comment: Yes I just realised 30 min ago thanks!

Comment: Please don’t add a “solved” section to your question. Instead, remove it to leave your question as it was originally, then just answer your own question (which is completely OK to do).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're always trying to match this pattern:

`func1(123, 456, 789)` (where "123" etc. are any arbitrary digits)

and replace it thus:

`func1(foo(123), bar(456), bazz(789))`

I think this should do it (in Vim anyway):

`:%s/(\(\d\+\), \(\d\+\), \(\d\+\))/(foo(\1), bar(\2), bazz(\3))/g`

Note that this requires uniform use of parentheses, commas, spaces, etc.  (A more robust solution would account for there sometimes being no space after a comma, or different numbers of spaces after opening parens, etc.)

Explanation -

```
:%s/(\(\d\+\), \(\d\+\), \(\d\+\))/(foo(\1), bar(\2), foobar(\3))/g
:%s/                              /                              /g   substitution delimeters; all lines; all occurences in a line
    (                                                                 opening paren of "func1()"
     \(    \)                                                         delimiters for first backreference
       \d                                                             Vim shorthand for "any digit" (instead of "[0-9]")
         \+                                                           Vim shorthand for "one or more instances of the preceding item"
                                                                      (Using the asterisk "*" matches zero or more, probably not what you want)
             ,                                                        Comma and space after the first backref capture group
               \(\d\+\),                                              Second backref capture group and trailing comma
                         \(\d\+\))                                    Third backref, and the function closing paren
                                   (foo(\1),                          Your "foo" label, opening paren, first backref, closing paren, comma
                                             bar(\2), foobar(\3)      Second and third labels, parens, and backrefs
                                                                )     Closing paren for "func1()"
```

In Vim, `:help regex` will be a good reference.  Use `ctrl-]` (control key and closing square bracket) to follow the internal links of the user manual.  Let us know please if this solves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** As MikeM mentions in the comments, the parenthesis needs to be escaped. So the correct regex looks like this:

`:%s/func1(\([0-9]*\), \([0-9]*\), \([0-9]*\))/func1(foo(\1), bar(\2), foobar(\3))/`

where in `\([0-9]*\)`, the `\(*\)` represents the variable `\1, \2` etc depending on the order it is declared. The `[0-9]*` means any number, where each digit can be between [0-9].